# Error en Eclipse: Enum class not found

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Veran, tengo una tabla llamada Seguro, con la siguientes caracteristicas.

```
    package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Seguro implements Serializable{
    public enum Sexo{
         Hombre,
         Mujer
    }

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int id;
Sexo sexo;


public Seguro() {}

public Seguro(Sexo sexo){
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Sexo getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(Sexo sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}
}
```

Y fichero Seguro.hbm.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro" >
    <id column="Id" name="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <property name="sexo" >
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Sexo</param>
        </type>
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el programa, me topo con este error:

```
Enum class not found: es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Sexo
```

¿Que estara fallando?

Edito: He probado este cambio en Seguro.hbm.xml:

```
<property name="sexo" >
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro.Sexo</param>
            <param name="type">4</param>
        </type>
    </property>
```

Pero me topo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El nombre de la clase es `es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro.Sexo`, ya que es una clase interna de `es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro`.

Comment: He probado eso pero no ha funcionado. He editado mi mensaje para mostrar una captura con el error.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado una solucion.
De entrada, he sacado al enumerado Sexo de la clase Seguro y lo he pasado a una clase Sexo:

```
package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

public enum Sexo{
    Hombre,
    Mujer
}
```

A partir de ahi, lo ultimo fue cambiar la configuración en Seguro.hbm.xml:

```
<property name="sexo" >
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Sexo</param>
        </type>
</property>
```